# Element selected is coming back undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Attempting to make simple multiplication/division program in CodePen, https://codepen.io/rynsp8/pen/PEGxpj,

but whenever I attempt to print the numbers to the console, or even run the function, it gives me nothing.  I prints out blank to the console, and gives me a 0 to pass into my HTML.

```
var numberOne = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
var numberTwo = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;

$('#multiply').click(function() {
  var product = numberOne * numberTwo;
  console.log(numberOne);
  return document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = product;
})

$('#divide').click(function() {
  var dividend = numberOne / numberTwo;
  return document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = dividend;
})
```

and here is my HTML

```
<div>
  <div id="container">
    <section id="numberInput">
      <input id="firstNumber" type="number" placeholder="Number 1">
      <input id="secondNumber" type="number" placeholder="Number 2">
    </section>
    <section id="buttonCTN">
      <button id="multiply" class="button">Multiply</button>
      <button id ="divide" class="button">Divide</button>
    </section>
    <section id="ansSEC">
      <p id="answer"></p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When are you executing those lines to set the value of numberOne and numberTwo?  I would suggest taking the `.value` off the assignment to numberOne and numberTwo and add it in the click handlers when you need them.  This way the variable reference the dom object, not a string, which would not be updated.  The dom though, is updated.

Comment: `var numberOne = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value` stores the value of the element with the id `firstNumber` in `numberOne` at the time of execution. But at that moment the input element is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var txtOne = document.getElementById("firstNumber");   
var txtTwo = document.getElementById("secondNumber");   

$('#multiply').click(function() {

var numberOne = txtOne.value;   //Now we can Get Updated value from textbox
var numberTwo = txtTwo.value;

var product = numberOne * numberTwo;
console.log(numberOne);
return document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = product;
})

$('#divide').click(function() {

var numberOne = txtOne.value;   //Now we can Get Updated value from textbox
var numberTwo = txtTwo.value;

 var dividend = numberOne / numberTwo;
 return document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = dividend;
})
```

You are getting values on page load, at that instant textboxes are blank.On click event values are not update in numberOne and numberTwo variables. You should get values on click event.